# How to select a single column with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to get the entire contents of a single column using Entity Framework 4? The same like this SQL Query:

```
SELECT Name FROM MyTable WHERE UserId = 1;
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) to do that. In your case it would go something like:

```
string Name = yourDbContext
  .MyTable
  .Where(u => u.UserId == 1)
  .Select(u => u.Name)
  .SingleOrDefault(); // This is what actually executes the request and return a response
```

If you are expecting more than one entry in response, you can use `.ToList()` instead, to execute the request. Something like this, to get the Name of everyone with age 30:

```
string[] Names = yourDbContext
  .MyTable
  .Where(u => u.Age == 30)
  .Select(u => u.Name)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: @guitarlass If you want to get a single result from your query then you'll need to do something like: `string s = db.Offices.Where(o => o.OfficeId == emp.OfficeId).Select(o => o.DepartmentId).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 6):

I'm a complete noob on Entity but this is how I would do it in theory...

```
var name = yourDbContext.MyTable.Find(1).Name;
```

If It's A Primary Key.

-- OR --

```
var name = yourDbContext.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(mytable => mytable.UserId == 1).Name;
```

-- OR --

For whole Column:

```
var names = yourDbContext.MyTable
.Where(mytable => mytable.UserId == 1)
.Select(column => column.Name); //You can '.ToList();' this....
```

But "oh Geez Rick, What do I know..."

Comment: This answer for Find doesn't work. Without select, it still fetches all columns from the table for single entity. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: You are absolutely right that all the columns will be fetched. Does it work, the answer is yes, is it efficient, no.

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ your query should look something like this:

```
public User GetUser(int userID){

return
(
 from p in "MyTable" //(Your Entity Model)
 where p.UserID == userID
 select p.Name
).SingleOrDefault();

}
```

Of course to do this you need to have an ADO.Net Entity Model in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the LINQ `select` clause and reference the property that relates to your Name column.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fetching a single item only then, you need use select before your *FirstOrDefault()/SingleOrDefault()*. And you can use anonymous object of the required properties.

```
var name = dbContext.MyTable.Select(x => new { x.UserId, x.Name }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == 1)?.Name;
```

Above query will be converted to this:

```
Select Top (1) UserId, Name from MyTable where UserId = 1;
```

For multiple items you can simply chain Select after Where:

```
var names = dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.UserId > 10).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Use anonymous object inside Select if you need more than one properties.